# $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of limit to prove that $\lim[(2n+1)/(5n-2)] = 2/5$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I've seen this proof before, and it was reduced to $9/(25n-10) < \varepsilon$, and eventually $9/5n < \varepsilon$. When I reduced it, I got $12/(25n - 10) < \varepsilon$, eventually providing:

$$
N > 12/5 \varepsilon. 
$$

I am wondering if this is correct, and where the $9$ in the numerator of the first proof came from in the first place?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

I can't know whether your proof is correct without knowing your whole proof… But here is the source of $9$.

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{2n+1}{5n-2} - \frac25
&= \frac{(2n+1) \times 5 - (5n-2) \times 2}{(5n-2) \times 5} \\
&= \frac{(10n+5) - (10n-4)}{25n - 10} \\
&= \frac{9}{25n - 10}. \\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I realized I messed up the initial rationalization of the fraction and carried the mistake through the rest of the proof. I appreciate the help.